# What is the best way for heroku PHP app directory?

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php

I am deploying a PHP (Laravel) app on Heroku.
I want to put Laravel files/directories at a directory.
Laravel `public directory` is defined at Procfile.

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 laravel/public/
```

Directories.

```
$ tree -L 1
.
├── Procfile
└── laravel   <--- here
   ├── app
   ├── artisan
   ├── composer.json
   ├── composer.lock
   ├── index.php
    ...
```

But composer.json must be located at repository root in Heroku.

What is the best way?

1. Give up to use directory and move files into root.
2. Specify `/laravel/composer.json` at Procfile. (Can I do this?)
3. Put `/composer.json` and specify vendor-dir into `/laravel/vendors`.

or any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation first? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure#the-public-directory

Comment: Not about public directory? `public directory` is defined at Procfile.